# Is there C++ method that allow to use function pointer multiple times without creating temporary variable?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, c++11, optimization

I have an idea or just a question about temporary variables replacement in some usage.

Less code with same functionality is good strategy to make code more easy to read.

For example if there is some function that return a pointer, and we need to use result pointer few times, than we need to code:

```
MyType *tempVariable=myFunctionGetNewTempValue();
tempVariable->doThis();
tempVariable->doSomethingElse();
delete tempVariable;
```

I suggest method to do the same with more readable code:

```
for_this(MyType *temp_variable, myFunctionGetNewTempValue())
{
temp_variable->doThis();
temp_variable->doSomethingElse();
delete temp_variable;
}
```

temp_variable should keep pointer function result of course.

And another example:

```
int temp_variable = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
myFunc1(temp_variable);
myFunc2(temp_variable/2);
```

Suggestion of replacement:

```
for_this(int temp_variable, 3*400*myVariable/1000.0)
{
myFunc1(temp_variable);
myFunc2(temp_variable/2);
}
```

Or maybe it should looks like this:

```
for_this(3*400*myVariable/1000.0)
{
myFunc1(this_result);
myFunc2(this_result/2);
}
```

temp_variable should be result number of calculation 3*400*myVariable/1000.0 and automatically freed after }

I usually do like this:

```
{
int tempVariable=3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
myFunc1(tempVariable);
myFunc2(tempVariable/2);
}
```

But making few block one by one looks confusing I think:

```
{
int tempVariable=3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
myFunc1(tempVariable);
myFunc2(tempVariable/2);
}
{
int tempVariable2=3*myVariable2/1000.0;
myFunc3(tempVariable2);
myFunc4(tempVariable2/2);
}
```

While reading this code I always ask question to myself "am I missed up 'else' between }{?".

This method also should be useful when temp_variable is some big structure that should be freed after usage. So we will not forget to free it in this case.

Is there C++ methods that allow to do something similar?

Comment: Why are you using pointers to begin with?  Can't you just use RAII?

Comment: Having a hard time seeing any function pointers whatsoever in this code. And your first example removed a clearly evident decl with initialization, wrapping it in a arguably-less-clear home-grown `for_this` construct. I see no win there at all.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I just tried to explain what I mean on examples. I don't mean it should be only function pointer.
It should be any result of calculations or function that stored in not visible (visually) temporary variable that automatically freed after }

Comment: … if you have multiple such blocks maybe you should consider whether you need multiple functions with less blocks...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Blocks in my code are different at all and can't be replaced by functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally **would not do this**, but you could write a macro like:

```
#define with(EXPR) for (auto _ : { EXPR })
```

It expands to a loop (with a body to be put afterwards) which defines a variable `_` holding your "temporary value".

It could then be used like:

```
with(3*400*myVariable/1000.0) {
    myFunc1(_);
    myFunc2(_/2);
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/gq6XnP)</kbd>

However, I don't see a real adavantage over just saying:

```
{
    auto _ = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
    myFunc1(_);
    myFunc2(_/2);
}
```

Comment: Second definition of `with` is broken. The curlies cannot happen between the type (`auto`) and the name of the variable. You can implement that macro, but not just so simply. Well, you can have: `with(temp, 3*400*myVariable/1000.) { … }` (i.e. have two arguments to the macro instead of just one), but at the end of the day this is a fragile solution [in the same way that the macros I wrote in my answer]

Comment: Of course, despite saying "don't do this," now some people are going to use this in production.  Hooray.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh yes, I was falsely thinking about `auto _ = EXPR` when that came to my mind.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: :) No, seriously… I would expect people to have at least a very small amount of common sense. I have seen this type of macros before, and I don't have an issue with them being explained *and* explicitly noted as **don't** do.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas With "fragile", do you mean for example that the user might not expect that `break` only exits this "doesn't look like but is a"-loop instead of the enclosing one he intended to actually break?

Comment: @leemes: For example :) `break` and `continue` change the meaning in the scope opened after the macro. Or they might not expect that the `with` macro above incurs the cost of a copy: say that the function returns a `std::string` with a large buffer, it gets stored in the *curlies* (`initializer_list<T>`?) and it gets then copied to the `_` variable in the loop. Using `auto&` or `auto&&` would remove one copy from there, so that might be an option… but playing with this type of tricks is brittle

Comment: @leemes, thanks for answer. It more close to thing I asked than other answers.
I'm not sure will I use it or not, but it was very interesting to read all answers. Thanks everyone, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

In C++ we use "smart pointers" such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to automatically release resources.  This technique is part of the "RAII" technique which is pervasive in C++ (and that's a good thing).  For example:

```
{
  std::unique_ptr<MyType> tempVariable(myFunctionGetNewTempValue());
  tempVariable->doThis();
  tempVariable->doSomethingElse();
  // tempVariable is destroyed, and so is its referent
}
```

As for the case where you simply want an integer to go out of scope at the end of a block:

```
{
  int temp_variable = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
  myFunc1(temp_variable);
  myFunc2(temp_variable/2);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know about smart pointers. But making {} without beginning (header or title) is confusing some time.
I'm making comments before { and it looks like this:

    //Some description title
    {
    int temp_variable = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0;
    myFunc1(temp_variable);
    myFunc2(temp_variable/2);
    }

But this version is more compact and readable I think:

    for_this(int temp_variable, 3*400*myVariable/1000.0)
    {
    myFunc1(temp_variable);
    myFunc2(temp_variable/2);
    }

So answer is no? There is no way to do things like this?

Comment: @IGHOR: I'd recommend that you learn the idioms in the language, rather than force your own personal preference. There is no advantage in the `for_this` other than personal taste, and there is a clear disadvantage: you are writing code in a form unfamiliar to most other devs. Is there a way, of course, it would not take much to create a macro that allowed for that code. But it would not be better than the simpler approach in this answer.

Comment: @IGHOR: So what you're saying is that you simply don't like the syntax of C++ and wish it had a different syntax?  That's fine, but it's not going to happen.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I like C++ syntax, just want to make things that often do be more compact, like using `foreach` instead of `for`.

Comment: @IGHOR: the syntax is my answer is as compact as what you proposed.

Comment: @IGHOR: There is no syntactical advantage in the `for_this`. Similar amount of typing and while you might not be used to blocks created in the middle of code (without a loop/conditional construct) you will soon be used to them if you ever program in a multithreaded environment and manually handle mutexes, as the common idiom is to use a guard around the critical operations in a similar manner: `{ auto lock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex); operation(); }` and have the destructor release the lock.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas How GCC has implemented STM syntax means more random blocks in the middle of code. :D

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this in production code, but for the sake of argument:

```
[](std::unique_ptr<auto> p) {
   p->doThis();
   p->doThat();
}(functionCreatesPointer());

[](auto x) {
   myFunc1(x);
   myFunc2(x);
}(3*400*myVariable/1000.);
```

Of course, a simpler approach is just to create a variable inside its own scope as John suggests, and you can even test for a valid pointer in the process without adding much boilerplate:

```
if (std::unique_ptr<MyType> p(myFunctionGetNewTempValue())) {
    tmpVariable->doThis();
    tmpVariable->doThat();
}
```

The optimizer will probably generate similar code in the three cases: local var, lambda, if (except for the test of null-ness in the `if` case). But I find John's code and the `if` simpler to understand for other maintainers of your code.

Of course, the language is flexible enough that it gives you enough rope to hang yourself while also blowing your foot with a rocket… (and I *really really* would not do this in production):

```
#define for_this(X) \
   if (bool stop = false) ; else \
      for (X; !stop; stop = true)
```

Then you can use:

```
for_this(int temp_variable = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0) {
    myFunc1(temp_variable);
    myFunc2(temp_variable);
}
```

that would expand to:

```
if (bool stop = false) ; else \
   for (int temp_variable = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0; !stop; stop = true) {
       myFunc1(temp_variable);
       myFunc2(temp_variable);
   }
```

and the optimizer will remove the condition and the loop. That can be further simplified by just passing the name of the variable and the initialization:

```
for_this(x = 3*400*myVariable/1000.0) { … }
```

where the only difference would be that the macro would add an additional `auto` to the `for`:

```
#define for_this(X) \
   if (bool stop = false) ; else \
      for (auto X; !stop; stop = true)
```

Please, *don't* :)

Comment: That interesting. Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Some programming languages have a "with" or "using" keyword which deals with automatically managing resources and sometimes even changes the meaning of the this pointer. Some examples are Pascal, Python, C# and VB6.

C++ has no such construct, and any attempt to create a custom solution will just obfuscate your code and create unnecessary complexity. Instead in C++ we use something called RAII, and there are tons of articles you could have a look at.

http://www.hackcraft.net/raii/

Comment: C++ does have `if (T* myThing = getThingIfPossible()) { use(*myThing); }` which has a little of the flavor of `with` in Python.  Not the same, though.

Comment: Yes. C++ has the same if statement semantics as C. You wouldn't be able to use that for non pointer types though.

Comment: You can still use it if your type converts to true, e.g. an int which won't be zero.  But this gets a bit subtle.

Comment: I'm not a big fan if implicit type conversions like this, but sometimes it's the only way to communicate scope of a variable for a conditional block.

Comment: @MorphingDragon: Well, there are different techniques to do *variable-injection* (general term for this kind of tricks: injecting a variable whose lifetime is restricted to a block opened by the user and outside of your control). I provided an example in my answer… I would avoid it in production, but it is fun to think how much rope the language provides to hang yourself.

Comment: Why would I use language constructs to hang myself when there's plenty of perfectly good "terrible programming habits" to go around. :p